# Add a link to the public profile in the invite list

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

After I invite a user to join careers I would like to check out their public profile.

[image: link]

The previously invited section should include a link to the public profile, if it exists, or the text "profile is private".

Answer (score 4):

The current implementation is such that if the profile is published there will be a **YES** in the published column. Additionally, if the profile is public, the **YES** will be a clickable link to that profile.